# MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message lis teners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I know this might flag as a duplicate solution but the solution on stack overflow is not working for me.

Problem

```
(node:5716) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message lis
teners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

My codebase is huge and I facing this error sometimes I don't know why it is happening. I tried to increase the listeners limit but unfortunately, it is not working.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.setMaxListeners(50)
```

**UPDATE**

After Some browsing, I run this command to trace warning

```
node --trace-warnings index.babel.js
```

Turns out be my socket.io code is the problem I am using socket.io with Redis. This is the error

```
node:14212) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message li
steners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:281:19)
    at RedisClient.addListener (events.js:298:10)
    at Namespace.<anonymous> (D:/newProject/services/socket.js:21:17)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Namespace.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Namespace.emit (D:\newProject\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:213:10)
    at D:\newProject\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:181:14
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

this is the code (But this code is for more specific tasks it will not execute all the time).

```
const redis = require('redis');
const config = require('../config');
const sub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);
const pub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);

sub.subscribe('spread');

module.exports = io => {
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    /* To find the User Login  */
    let passport = socket.handshake.session.passport; 

    if (typeof passport !== 'undefined') {
      socket.on('typing:send', data => {
        pub.publish('spread', JSON.stringify(data));
      });

      sub.on('message', (ch, msg) => {
        // This is the Exact line where I am getting this error
        io.emit(`${JSON.parse(msg).commonID}:receive`, { ...JSON.parse(msg) });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: This is 99% of the time, because we forget to Unhook our event listener during the summary stage of our control flow.  You must always unhook every event listener you add to the global execution context.  Are you building a React application?

Comment: @TobiahRex Hello Thanks for the comment But i am newbie just getting started step by step can you give some example.

Comment: I was planning on giving you an example once I understand your use case.  Hence why i asked if you are building a React application as I see you added the "reactjs" tag to your question. So, what's the use case?

Comment: Yes the stack is Node.js/React.js/Mysql/Redis ,If i use the app so fast the error is appearing.

Comment: Does this library leave it up to the user to call a destructor?

Comment: Well, you have to find the leaks in your code.
Here is a resource to help you out. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/?hl=en

Comment: @RahilAhmad That's not even remotely related.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default limit for [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_eventemitter_defaultmaxlisteners) is 10. You can increase it with the emitter.setMaxListeners. My suggestion is not to change it unless and until explicitly required, listeners are increased because you didn't unsubscribe. Now to your code.

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const config = require('../config');
const sub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);
const pub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);

sub.subscribe('spread');

module.exports = (io) => {
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // this callback will be executed for all the socket connections.
    let passport =
      socket.handshake.session.passport; /* To find the User Login  */

    if (typeof passport !== 'undefined') {
      socket.on('typing:send', (data) => {
        pub.publish('spread', JSON.stringify(data));
      });

      // this is where you are subscribing for each and every socket connected to your server
      sub.on('message', (ch, msg) => {
        // this is the Exact line where I am getting this error

        // whereas you are emitting messages on socket manager, not on the socket.
        io.emit(`${JSON.parse(msg).commonID}:receive`, { ...JSON.parse(msg) });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Now if we analyze the above code then if you open 20 socket connections to your server it will subscribe 20 times, here it is going wrong.
Now if your requirement is to listen for the message published on Redis at the server level and then emit it on io  then your code should be like below

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const config = require('../config');
const sub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);
const pub = redis.createClient(config.REDIS.port, config.REDIS.host);

sub.subscribe('spread');

module.exports = (io) => {
  sub.on('message', (ch, msg) => {
    // this is the Exact line where I am getting this error
    io.emit(`${JSON.parse(msg).commonID}:receive`, { ...JSON.parse(msg) });
  });

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    let passport =
      socket.handshake.session.passport; /* To find the User Login  */

    if (typeof passport !== 'undefined') {
      socket.on('typing:send', (data) => {
        pub.publish('spread', JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 20):

The built-in [`events`](https://devdocs.io/node~8_lts/events) module in [`node.js`](https://nodejs.org/) (a version of which is bundled into your frontend app if you compile with [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/) or [`browserify`](http://browserify.org/)) makes some assumptions about your code.  Sometime, somewhere, somebody decided that if you had `X` number of listeners registered, then *surely* you've got a memory leak.  And sometimes it is correct, and reminds you correctly to go find the leaks.

I've received this warning many times, but usually only for two specific reasons, both of which have simple solutions:

---

### Problem 1:  Mismatched bound event listener functions

Your component may look like this, where you are using a component method as the event listener, and you are binding it *as you register it*.

```
import events from '../lib/events' // some singleton event emitter

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    events.addEventListener('some-event', this.myMethod.bind(this))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    events.removeEventListener('some-event', this.myMethod.bind(this))
  }

  myMethod() {
    // does something
  }

  render() {
    // gotta have this too
  }
}
```

The problem here is that [`function.bind`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/bind) creates a **new function** each time, such that the function you are trying to remove is not the same as the function you added.  Consequently, the added functions keep adding-up (bad pun), and you do in fact have a real memory leak.

### Solution 1: Bind your methods early

Bind your method early, commonly in the `constructor()`.  Then you can refer to the bound version each time, ensuring that the function removed is the same as the function added.

```
import events from '../lib/events' // some singleton event emitter

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    // bind your method early so the function removed
    // is the same as the function added
    this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    events.addEventListener('some-event', this.myMethod)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    events.removeEventListener('some-event', this.myMethod)
  }

  myMethod() {
    // does something
  }

  render() {
    // gotta have this too
  }
}
```

---

### Problem 2: Lots and lots of event listeners

Sometimes you've really done your homework and double-checked that you've bound your listeners early as needed, and then removed them all at the appropriate places.  Then you look closer and find that you're doing something like this:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent' // same component above

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.largeArray.map(MyComponent) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Suppose `this.props.largeArray` had 50, 100, or maybe 250 elements.  This means that (by design!) you are rendering 250 instances of `MyComponent`, each of which is registering another unique event listener.

Fear not!  This is totally valid code, and does not have a memory leak.  But it does blow through the max-listeners limit that somebody, sometime, somewhere decided arbitrarily to help protect you.

### Solution 2: Switch to using [`eventemitter3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3)

If you decide that you've done your homework, and double-checked all the things, and are (by design!) registering lots of event listeners, then the simplest solution is to switch to using [`eventemitter3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3), which is a drop-in replacement for node's `events` module, except faster, and browser-compatible, and *doesn't set a max-listeners limit for you.*

Usage is just like the built-in `events` module:

```
const EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3')
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
```

Comment: That's is a brief example Thanks .But I updated my Question with the exact line where I am getting this warning.

Comment: thanks, this is a much better & practical answer with guidance to solutions compared to other workarounds.

Answer (score 15):

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. **11** message lis teners added. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

By default, a maximum of **10** listeners can be registered for any single event, and we got **11** Ohno

```
// Change to 80 or 150 whatever and see what happens
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 70;
require('events').defaultMaxListeners = 70;

  process.on('warning', function (err) {
    if ( 'MaxListenersExceededWarning' == err.name ) {
      console.log('o kurwa');
      // write to log function
      process.exit(1); // its up to you what then in my case script was hang

    }
  });
```

Comment: Initial require worked for me!! Will memory leak be any issue?

Comment: First require did it for me too. I'm using material-ui DataGrid and when I added an 11th column I get a similar error, in part: `11 colResizing: start listeners added`. I feel like there is likely a way to directly point to the "colResizing: start" listener group and tell it specifically my column number (when over ten). Setting to 11 squashed my issue.

Comment: b78vcnv 8l0jg0pgm9p,.=]0/-=

Comment: how would you do this for .mjs file? I get `require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead` error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended way to add and remove event listeners within *React* Components - using *LifeCycle* methods.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
    windowWidth: window.innderWidth,
   };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Current window width: {this.state.windowWidth}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's important to remember that `window` is within the global execution context. Therefore every time you add an event listener, you're asking the global scope to

1. instantiate another listener.
2. track that listener using global memory by reference - in this case `resize`
3. continue tracking the listener until told not to.

If you never tell the global scope to remove those listeners, then the global memory - as allocated by your browser settings - will slowly evaporate and crash your browser & application, or the client's browser if already in production.  One must be VERY careful and VERY aware when they manipulate global memory.

If you want to understand (if you don't already) WHY the lifecycle methods in React Component's work, I would highly recommend you look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) at React's *Reconciliation* lifecycle.  One can't accurately call themselves a *"React Developer"* and not be intimately familiar with *Reconciliation*.

**Note** This Component is using babel to transpile parts of the code: `import`, and assigned custom method `handleResize` with only using arrow functions.  If you need assistance in setting up the environment, you can refer to [this blog post](https://medium.com/@tobiahrex/es6-class-static-props-in-react-7b7480381e06) i wrote that should make it understandable.

Good luck.

Comment: Hello first of thanks for your brief answer but I am pretty sure and i rechecked I've cleared all of my event listeners.But i am still getting this error ```(node:7732) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message lis
teners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
``` and I am using mysql as my database

Comment: @Nane Errors aren't lying to you. They're logical arguments that are never wrong. So although i'm sure you believe you cleared everything, the error is saying that you didn't.  Good luck!

Comment: @Nane this resource can be useful to find the memory leaks. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/?hl=en

Comment: I updated my Question with the exact line where I am getting this warning.