# (node:6261) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am getting this error on nodejs app:
Node version: v8.11.1

```
(node:6261) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase
limit
```

I have a very simple code of pushing notification to IOS device using node-apn. **The code is working fine, I am receiving push notifications on device as well**

```
var express               = require('express')
  , serverPort            = 6900
  , app                   = express()
  , http                  = require('http')
  , https                 = require('https')
  , fs                    = require('fs')
  , apn                   = require('apn')
;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello!');
  res.end();
});

server.listen(serverPort, (err) => {

  if(err) { return console.log("Something bad happened", err); }
});

var apnOptions = {

  token: {
  },
  production: false 
};

var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(apnOptions);
var note        = new apn.Notification();

note.expiry     = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge      = 3;
note.sound      = "ping.aiff";
note.alert      = "\uD83D\uDCE7 \u2709 You have a new message";
note.payload    = { 'messageFrom': 'John Appleseed' };
note.topic      = "com.example.test";

apnProvider.send(note, '6A752501A5DAFF9DCSFRE56C5B0E699385CD14B586CEF4B9C5012DDA4').then( (result) => {

  console.log(result); 
});
```

The issue here is with APN code, because as soon as I comment APN code, I dont face this error anymore. 
Can anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code? I feel like I have done everything right here but still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50709059/1461424), or [this comment in Github](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1051#issuecomment-354811768)? Unfortunately, it is likely that the problem is in `node-apn`. Please post a stack trace and the `node-apn` version you are using.

Comment: `node-apn` 2.2.0 (latest). The stacktrace isn't helpful, unfortunately -- it starts inside a process.callbackTrampoline and processImmediate, so the real trace is lost to the ether (a nodejs deficiency).

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions. Both are related to updating maximum number of listeners and both should be added at the beginning of your code.

1- You may set 0 for event listeners like below, risky because you are basically removing the limit:

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter()
emitter.setMaxListeners(0)
```

2- Globally fixes the error, set a high value as maximum like

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
```

Reference 1: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html#emitter.setMaxListenershttps://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html#emitter.setMaxListeners

Reference 2: [possible EventEmitter memory leak detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected)

Comment: @StormTrooper sure, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

`node-apn` has [several issues](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1051#issuecomment-354811768), try to use `node-apn-http2`.

`npm install node-apn-http2`

Replace `, apn = require('apn')`

with `, apn = require('node-apn-http2')`