# (node:125008) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**(node:125008) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit**

How exactly do I increase the number of listener events? I've searched around and none of the methods I've tried have worked : (

Comment: what did the method mentioned in the error you posted (`emitter.setMaxListeners()`) do when you called it?  Also, how many events are you trying to listen to at once?  What is it you are trying to do that you need to increase the limit?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709059/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-mess

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the manual: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

What version of Node is this? What other code do you have? That isn't normal behavior.

In short, its: `process.setMaxListeners(0);`

Also see: [node.js - request - How to “emitter.setMaxListeners()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners)

I'd like to point out here that that warning is there for a reason and there's a good chance the right fix is not increasing the limit but figuring out why you're adding so many listeners to the same event. Only increase the limit if you know why so many listeners are being added and are confident it's what you really want.

I found this page because I got this warning and in my case there was a bug in some code I was using that was turning the global object into an EventEmitter! I'd certainly advise against increasing the limit globally because you don't want these things to go unnoticed.

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply, I managed to fix the issue on my own after a while but I'll make sure to read the page you have provided me for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

11 ready listeners added

means you have 11 `<Discord.client>.on('ready', <function>)`

so node.js warns you because that uses a lot of memory. You probably have nested events somewhere so it makes 11 ready events.

Comment: I had many events on the discord.js bot just on the main index.js file, I removed some as I deemed them unnecessary for the bots base operation. And, now I've split my bot from its publically available futures and private futures onto multiple separate bots to keep the bot public and not have constant downtime and issues on it and so I can test things on my own space with no need to worry about downtime on a personal private bot. Sorry for the late reply by the way.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved with this line:

process.setMaxListeners(Infinity);