# MaxListenersExceededWarning occurs when promise.all is used in while loop

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am using promise in while loop. When about 50 promises is executed, MaxListenersExceededWarning warning start to alert. So I wonder what relation is between EventEmitter and Promise. and How to fix my code to avoid this warning.

I tried to decrease number of items in contentList. and when number is lower than fifty there is no warning. but when number is over fifty, it start to warn.

```
async (req, res, next) => {
    let repository = new ContentRep();

    let contentList = (await repository.getContentList({category: 'allContent'})).contentList;

    while (contentList.length > 0) {
        let taskSize = contentList.length > 5 ? 5 : contentList.length;
        let subList = contentList.slice(0, taskSize);
        contentList = contentList.slice(taskSize, contentList.length);
        let contentPromises = [];

        subList.forEach(row => {
            contentPromises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
                repository.getTemplateInfo(row.category, row.content)
                    .then(templateInfo => {
                        resolve(templateInfo);
                    });
            }));

        })

        await Promise.all(contentPromises);
    }
    return contentList;
}
```

error code

```
(node:63176) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message lis teners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709059/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-mess)

Answer (score -1):

This warning commonly occurs because of memory leakage and internal errors. 
Increase the limit of maximum events that you can register will remove the warning

Add this code to your main file

```
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
```

Comment: This hides the issue without fixing the real problem.