# wakeup listeners added to [Connection]

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Initially I was getting this error

```
(node:24561) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

then I increased the limit to 100 still it is getting exceeded

```
(node:24561) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 101 wakeup listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I don't understand the reason behind the memory leak, can anyone please explain this error `listeners added to [Connection]`

This is the error stack trace

```
WARN_ALERT MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 101 wakeup listeners added to [Connection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:386:17)
    at Connection.addListener (events.js:402:10)
    at Connection.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:855:35)
    at Connection.once (events.js:433:8)
    at Connection._send (~/codeFile/node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/connection.js:355:10)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
```

Comment: This looks like looped recursion. Most probably callback either being called infinitely or it triggers itself again and again. Could you post the code around **domain.js:137**?

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov there is no file with `domain.js`, might be in some module

Comment: I am quite sure there is : **at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)**. Anyway, we can't help you without any code that can lead us in the right direction

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v12.16.1/lib/domain.js this is the file present in main Nodejs

Comment: Take a look at this issue. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709059/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-mess) . Your connect code would be very useful as well. As there is very limited information currently