# Javascript non-async function promise problem, how to fix it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have 2 function: the first one is: `readCSV` that reads a csv file line by line, every lines contains a site name and for each one I have to call a web crawler.

the first function is:

```
async function readCSV(){
 
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./topm.csv');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    var currentline=line.split(",");
    var current_site = "http://www."+currentline[1];
    await crawling("http://www."+currentline[1]) 
  }
}
```

and the other one is: `crawling(web_page)` that crawls the page.

```
async function crawling(web_page){
  try{

      new Crawler().configure({depth: 1})
      .crawl(web_page, function onSuccess(page) {
        console.log(page.url);

      });


  }catch(error){
      console.log("Error: "+error.message);
  }
}
```

every function is async, but when I call `readCSV` I noticed that the line with `await crawling(.....)` doesn't wait the end of each one and execute a lot of pages in parallel, giving me for some pages this waring:
`(node:757) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added to [Request]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`

I also noticed that with a file having 100 lines (100 web pages) the crawler is calling just 84 times... I don't understand why

At the end I tried to add a promise inside readCSV function, in this way:

```
async function readCSV(){
 

  
  
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./topm.csv');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });


  for await (const line of rl) {
    var currentline=line.split(",");
    var current_site = "http://www."+currentline[1];
    //await crawling("http://www."+currentline[1])
    await (new Promise( resolve => {
      new Crawler().configure({depth: 1})
      .crawl(current_site, async (page) => {
          console.log(page.url);
          

          resolve();
      });
    }));
  }

}
```

But in this way it works only for the first 4 site (to compile I need to add this `--unhandled-rejections=strict`)

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise.

I think your problem is that your `crawling` function doesn't actually return a promise. So the code `await crawling("http://www."+currentline[1])` evaluates immediately, returning the return value of the `crawling` function, which is `undefined`.

It is possible that this is the fix:

```
  await new Crawler().configure({depth: 1})
  //^^^
  .crawl(web_page, function onSuccess(page) {
    console.log(page.url);

  });
```

It depends on what is returned by the `crawl` method, but if it returns a promise, that should be right.

Comment: sorry, My last comment was wrong. I insert you part of code, it works but I have the same error of setMaxlistener, and the sites checked at end are 84 and not 100

Comment: Good answer, though in this instance I'd `s/return/await/` or the try/catch block is defeated. Also `s/null/undefined/`.

Comment: Your question about listeners might be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709059/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-mess There's not much in this code that deals with events, so I doubt I can help.