# Does the proxy.conf.json have something to do with Node listeners?

Tags: angular

I've been researching for a while because we encountered [this warning, (MaxListenersExceededWarning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709059/maxlistenersexceededwarning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-mess) while running our Angular 14 project. We are utilizing a proxy.conf file to route our API requests. Given that we are utilizing Java microservices for the backend the file has a considerable amount of proxies(14).

My question is, could this MaxListenersExceededWarning be related to the proxy file? I attempted to remove some proxies from the file and the warning disappeared. In that case, does it imply that we need to increase the limit? However, I'm uncertain, and I'm not sure if there might be a memory leak somewhere, as suggested by the warning.